# How to do firebase push notification with redirect with payload data in flutter.?

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, flutter-local-notification

Here is my code below :-

```
var typeId = message!=null?message.data["payload"]:payload;

if(typeId["type"]=="XYZ"){
//Navigate to a screen

}else{}
```

this is not working and throwing exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is because of you've not decoded your `message.data["payload"]`.
Because Data payload contains custom key-value pairs not a JSON format. you have to decode it.

here is your solution:

```
var typeId = message!=null ?  json.decode(message.data["payload"]) : payload;

if(typeId["type"]=="XYZ"){

//Navigate to a screen

}
else{

}
```

happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in your Flutter project by adding the firebase_messaging package to your pubspec.yaml file and configuring your Firebase project.
2. In your main.dart file, add the following code to set up a Firebase Cloud Messaging listener:

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((token) {
  print('Token: $token');
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');
  print('Message notification: ${message.notification}');
  // handle your notification here
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');
  // handle your notification here
});
```

3. In the `onMessage` and `onMessageOpenedApp` listeners, you can handle the received notification data and show a notification to the user using the flutter_local_notifications package. You can also use the Navigator class to navigate to a specific screen in your app.

For example, you can use the following code to show a notification with a payload data and redirect the user to a specific screen when the notification is clicked:

```
    Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
      var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your channel id',
        'your channel name',
        'your channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        showWhen: false,
      );
      var platformChannelSpecifics =
          NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0,
        message.notification?.title,
        message.notification?.body,
        platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: message.data['screen'],
      );
    }
    
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');
      print('Message notification: ${message.notification}');
      showNotification(message);
    });
    
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');
      String screen = message.data['screen'];
      if (screen != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, screen);
      }
    });
```

In the code above, the `showNotification` function is called to show a notification with the title and body of the received message. The payload parameter is used to pass the screen name to navigate to when the user clicks the notification.

When the notification is clicked, the `onMessageOpenedApp` listener is triggered, and the screen value is extracted from the message data. If the screen value is not null, the Navigator class is used to navigate to the specified screen.

Make sure to handle any errors that may occur while implementing push notifications and follow the guidelines provided by the Firebase documentation for secure and reliable push notifications.